# Is it possible to get the same object, with different keys?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to convert all `name_t`s in *this* object:

```
object:4 [▼
  0 => {#161 ▼
    +"id": 1
    +"name_t": "coffee"
  }
  1 => {#194 ▼
    +"id": 2
    +"name_t": "Tea"
  }
  2 => {#195 ▼
    +"id": 3
    +"name_t": "Chocolate"
  }
  3 => {#196 ▼
    +"id": 4
    +"name_t": "To chocklate"
  }
]
```

to `name_c`s, like in *this* object:

```
object:4 [▼
  0 => {#161 ▼
    +"id": 1
    +"name_c": "coffee"
  }
  1 => {#194 ▼
    +"id": 2
    +"name_c": "Tea"
  }
  2 => {#195 ▼
    +"id": 3
    +"name_c": "Chocolate"
  }
  3 => {#196 ▼
    +"id": 4
    +"name_c": "To chocklate"
  }
]
```

I've already tried this function:

```
 public function prepareToFilter($objects)
        {
        $temp = 0;
        foreach($objects as $object)
        {

            $prepared[$temp] = ['id' => $object->id, 'name_c' => $object->name_t];
            $temp++;
        }
        return $prepared;
    }
```

..but it gave me an array, instead of an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `array_map` function, and cast the values to an object:

```
public function prepareToFilter($data)
{
    return array_map(function ($item) {
        return (object) [
            'id'     => $item->id,
            'name_c' => $item->name_t,
        ];
    }, $data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try =>

```
    foreach($objects as $object)
    {
        $object->name_c = $object->name_t;
        unset($object->name_t);
    }
```